# Lightning aura:attribute with custom List type returns error?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

The Lightning developer guide says that an aura:attribute can contain a List of custom apex type objects, like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="colorPalette" type="List<docSampleNamespace.Color>" />
```

However, when I try this, I get this error message:

*Message: The value of attribute "type" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.: Source*

Is this just not implemented yet in the dev preview, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is XML does not allow the use of unescaped < or > characters. In Apex (which is where Lightning Components gets its type system) arrays and lists are equivalent. We typically use array notation in attribute defs because you do not have to `&lt; and &gt;` encode the []. Try this instead:

```
<aura:attribute name="colorPalette" type="docSampleNamespace.Color[]"/>
```

Comment: That works, thanks. One thing I eventually figured out is that you need to add the @AuraEnabled keyword to the public variables you want to be able to reference in the custom type class or you just get empty objects.