# save two records in two objects with a single save button with lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, actionfunction, form, javascript-controller, create-records

**I have two objects**: question and answer, in one form.
the first 3 fields belong to the question object.
dynamic form belongs to the response object.

I created two actions in the client-side controller that invoked two other actions in the server-side controller.
 when I click on the button save, I receive the alert as if everything went well but nothing really save.

**below the screenshot**:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**and code in client-side controller.**

```
  Save: function(component, event, helper) {
```

if (helper.validateRequiredQuestion(component, event)) {
            var action1 = component.get("c.saveQuestions");
            action1.setParams({
                "Quest": component.get("v.QuestionLi")
            });
            // set call back 
            action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS" ) {
                    component.set("v.QuestionLi", []);
                    helper.createObjectDataa(component, event);
                    alert('question saved');
                }
            });
            // enqueue the server side action
            $A.enqueueAction(action1);
        }
       if (helper.validateRequired(component, event)) {
            var action = component.get("c.saveReponses");
            action.setParams({
                "ListReponse": component.get("v.ReponseList")
            });
            // set call back 
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS" ) {
                    component.set("v.ReponseList", []);
                    helper.createObjectData(component, event);
                    alert('reponse saved');
                }
            });
            // enqueue the server side action
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }

```
},
```

**Server-side controller**

```
public with sharing class SurveyItelios_addDeleteController {
   @AuraEnabled  
    public static void saveReponses(List ListReponse){
        Insert ListReponse;
    }
   @AuraEnabled  
    public static void saveQuestions(List Quest){
        Insert Quest;
    }
}
```

**here is the code component**

```
<aura:handler name="DeleteRowEvt" event="c:SurveyItelios_DeleteRowEvt" action="{!c.removeDeletedRow}"/>
<aura:handler name="AddRowEvt" event="c:SurveyItelios_AddNewRowEvt" action="{!c.addNewRow}"/>

<aura:attribute name="ReponseList" type="surveyitelios_question_options__c[]"/> 
  <!--aura:attribute name="objInfo" type="surveyitelios_input_types__c" default="{sobjectType : 'surveyitelios_input_types__c'}" /-->
```

Questions

```
                     default="{'sobjectType':'surveyitelios_questions__c',

                    'Name': ''}"

                  />     
  <lightning:layout >

    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">

         <form class="slds-form--stacked">   

            <lightning:input aura:id="Name" label="Question name"

                             name="Name"

                             value="{!v.QuestionLi.Name}"

                             required="true"/>        
             <lightning:input aura:id="input_type_id__c" label="id type"

                             name="input_type_id__c"

                             value="{!v.QuestionLi.input_type_id__c}"

                             required="true"/>

             <lightning:input aura:id="surveyitelios_survey__c" label="id survey"

                             name="surveyitelios_survey__c"

                             value="{!v.QuestionLi.surveyitelios_survey__c}"

                             required="true"/>
</form>

    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Les réponses
    
 
     
        
            
                
                    S.No

```
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="name">Choix</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Valeur">Valeur</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Question">Id Question</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>    
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ReponseList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
            <c:SurveyItelios_dynamicRowItem ReponseInstance="{!item}" rowIndex="{!index}" />
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<!--Save Button which is call Save js function on click --> 
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.Save}" style ="margin-left:1%;">Save</button>
```

**Helper Code**

```
({
    createObjectData: function(component, event) {
        var RowItemList = component.get("v.ReponseList");
        RowItemList.push({
            'sobjectType': 'surveyitelios_question_options__c',
            'Name': '',
            'option_value__c': '',
            'question_id__c':''
        });
        component.set("v.ReponseList", RowItemList);
    },

        createObjectDataa: function(component, event) {
        // get the contactList from component and add(push) New Object to List  
        var RowItemListt = component.get("v.QuestionLi");
        RowItemListt.push({
            'sobjectType': 'surveyitelios_questions__c', 
            'Name': '',
            'input_type_id__c': '',
            'surveyitelios_survey__c':''
        });
        component.set("v.QuestionLi", RowItemListt);
    },


    // helper function for check if first Name is not null/blank on save  
    validateRequired: function(component, event) {
        var isValid = true;
        var allContactRows = component.get("v.ReponseList");
        for (var indexVar = 0; indexVar < allContactRows.length; indexVar++) {
            if (allContactRows[indexVar].option_value__c == '') {
                isValid = false;
                alert('Input type Name Can\'t be Blank on Row Number ' + (indexVar + 1));
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    },
      validateRequiredQuestion: function(component, event) {
        var isValid = true;
        var allContactRows = component.get("v.QuestionLi");
        for (var indexVar = 0; indexVar < allContactRows.length; indexVar++) {
            if (allContactRows[indexVar].Name == '') {
                isValid = false;
                alert('Question Name Can\'t be Blank on Row Number ' + (indexVar + 1));
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    },

})
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Turn on server-side logging and see if anything unexpected appears there. You can also use your browser's Network tab inits Developer Tools to check what is sent and received.

Comment: Why don't you paste your code with SE code editor...it's really tough to read ...

Comment: i will update my question and change the screenshot to se code editor

Comment: @KeithC i turned server-side logging , and 
nothing has appeared.

Comment: 1. Post your helper code as well. 2. Edit your component code as well, seems few things are missing. 3. Post your apex code reflecting what debug messages you have put in there.

Comment: @JayantDas 1-  added the helper code 2- what kinds of things please?

Comment: The component code is not properly formatted, so you may like to format that. Post the component code in its entirety in one block.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my recommendation:

1. QuestionLi Attribute is defined as simple object but when it's passed to server, you are assuming it's list of object. Update this attribute as List of object.
2. As a best practice, your apex method should return some value to identify, possibly `String`. Keep your DML in try catch block and return exception if any occurs so that you can debug properly.

   public static String saveQuestions (....){

   ```
      try{

         insert ...

         return 'SUCCESS';

      catch(Excpetion e){ return e.getMessage();}
   }
   ```

Comment: after trying ur suggestioniI have: invalid type exception

Comment: May be you are not initializing your object or something...it's tough to guess what could be the reason..may be these link can help you..  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm    https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56989/lightning-auraattribute-with-custom-list-type-returns-error

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved.

I just replace the two actions in the client-side controller with one action.
And in Server-side controller i have one action with two parameters (two records for two objects ).

here is my code in controller :

```
public with sharing class SurveyItelios_addDelController {
   @AuraEnabled  
    public static void  savequestion(surveyitelios_questions__c quest,List rep){
        insert quest;
        insert rep;
    }
}
```

thank youuu all :D